# Custom Debug Engine for Interpreter

Tags: xml, visual-studio, debugging, interpreter

can anyone provide me some detailed information in how to write a custom debug engine for Visual Studio especially for an interpreter?

I have a custom xml document which describes a workflow and i've a runner (interpreter) for this which interprets and executes each element of the xml file at runtime (C#).

Now i want to create a custom debug engine which is able to step over those xml-elements.

I've found some basic examples of how to write such a debug engine but i have a big question:

How does the runtime (debuggee) communicate with the debug engine?
For example the debug engine sends a "Step over" command. But what do i need to receive this event in my app? How do i know when to execute the next step?
I'am sure i also need to tell the debug engine when the action has been completed, but how?

Does anyone of you has done something similar and can provide me some samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some more research on hard mode vs soft mode debugging:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/02/09/hardmode-vs-softmode/

I believe you have to implement a soft mode debugger to get this to work. That means having a thread (or threads) running in your interpreter that you communicate with from your debug engine.

Here's another link that describes how to write a debug engine for Visual Studio

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Visual-Studio-Debug-Engine-c2e21c0e

That example is a hard mode debugger though. There's no sample for soft-mode for VS that I know of.

Comment: Thx, the first link helped me a lot.
Also this repo is helping: https://github.com/techl/MonoRemoteDebugger